# How to pass Javascript value to label server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a gridview that contains two(2) ASPxComboBox the value of the second Combo box is base on the value of the first combo box. DevExpress demos and sample are a bit complicated and time consuming so I think of a workaround that when the selected item of combo box is exchange the value will store in a label. And I will get the value of label to store in dropdown. But I don't know how to pass the value of label in server side. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Here's my code.

**FrontEnd**

```
<asp:Label ID="LblProduct" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>   

<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2" OnRowDataBound="ASPxGridView2_RowDataBound" ClientInstanceName="GridV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="forprod" KeyFieldName = "ppdtl_no">
<columns>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="fld_product" Name="Dd_product" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" VisibleIndex="3">
<SettingsHeaderFilter>
<DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
</SettingsHeaderFilter>
<EditItemTemplate>
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBoxProduct" runat="server" DataSourceID="pp_prod" TextField="pp_ppname" ValueField="pp_ppcode">
<ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { OnProductChanged(s); }"></ClientSideEvents>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>


<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="fld_type" Name="dd_type" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" VisibleIndex="4">
<SettingsHeaderFilter>
<DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
</SettingsHeaderFilter>
<EditItemTemplate>
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBoxType" runat="server" DataSourceID="pp_type" TextField="pp_codetype" ValueField="pp_codetype">
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
</columns>
</ASPxGridView>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function OnProductChanged(s, e) {
          var selected_index = s.lastSuccessValue;
          var aa = document.getElementById('LblProduct').innerText = selected_index;

      }
      onload = OnProductChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ClientID property of any element you run at server level in your selector. To achieve this, you have to write the JavaScript inside the file with your label, and then use `<%= LblProduct.ClientID %>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<%= LblProduct.ClientID %>');
</script>
```

Look at your project during runtime with Inspect - you will see the ID after compilation is not `LblProduct`, but something similar to `ProjectName_PageName_ContentPlaceHolderName_LblProduct`.

You could also just copy-paste that, though it's not open to change.